# 8 different people in groups of 2

Tags: combinatorics

Let's say we have a rectangular table with 4 chairs in each side, for a total of 8 chairs. We also have 4 groups of 2 people each representing different companies, for a total of 8 different people.

Q: We want to sit each group composed of 2 people together. In how many ways can we do it ?

My incorrect answer: 2!⁴ * 4!

Thank you

Comment: What constitutes "sitting together"?  Is it sitting next to each other, side by side, or across from each other, on opposite sides of the table?

Comment: next to each other, which implies that they have to be on the same side @BrianTung

Answer (score 1, accepted):

number of ways to arrange 4 groups=4!

number of ways to arrange 2 people inside the groups=2!

*By fundamental principle of multiplication*,
we have number of ways=(2!)^4*(4!)

but because of horizontal and vertical symmetry,
number of ways =((2!)^4*(4!))/(2*2)

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: i dont understand what you mean with those symmetries

Comment: for example, take any one specific arrangement.Now flip the whole arrangement upside down.The new arrangement will be nothing but the old arrangement viewed from the upper side of the table.Same thing will happen if you flip it from left to right.Thus number of fundamental arrangements will be obtained when the total is divided by 4

Comment: okay thank you @Chand